# If $\tan A+\sec A=e^x$, find $\cos A$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan A+\sec A=e^x$, find $\cos A$

Here is what I've tried:

\begin{align}&\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}+\frac{1}{\cos A}&=e^x\\
\implies&\frac{1+\sin A}{\cos A}&=e^x\end{align}

Now, I've squared both sides, but, in vain. How should I continue? Am I proceeding wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

As $\sec A+\tan A=e^x$

Now  $\sec A-\tan A=\dfrac1{\sec A+\tan A}=?$

Can you solve for $\sec A?$

Finally $\cos A\cdot\sec A=?$

Comment: I solved it! Kudos for the hint.

Comment: @Abhishekstudent, If you are interested, try a detour using : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 2):

HINT

shorthand instead of latex

$$ \frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}}{c} +  \frac{1}{c} = e $$

Simplify with algebra after squaring, make it a quadratic in $c= \cos A.$ Then one root is $ c= \cos A=0,$ and the other

$$ c\,=  \frac{2e}{e^2+1}$$

$$ c= \cos A =  \frac{1}{\cosh x }$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{1+\sin A}{\cos A}&=\frac{(\cos \frac A2+\sin \frac A2)^2}{\cos^2 \frac A2-\sin^2 \frac A 2}\\
&=\frac{\cos \frac A2+\sin \frac A2}{\cos \frac A2-\sin \frac A 2}\\
\end{align}
implying that $$(1-e^x)\cos \frac A2 =-(1+e^x)\sin \frac A2$$
the rest shall be doable for you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan A+\sec A=e^x\implies\tan A+\frac{1}{\cos A}=e^x\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\implies\frac{1}{\cos A}=e^x-\tan A\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\implies\cos A=\frac{1}{e^x-\tan A}.$$

Comment: supposing x = 1 - what is cos A then equal to?

Comment: When $x=1$ then $$\cos A=\frac{1}{e-\tan A}.$$ But if you're looking for an answer not in terms of $A$ then see other answers above.

Answer (score -2):

Given 
tanA+secA=e^x.   ------------(I)
Calculate.   ( secA-tanA) using tan^2A+1=sec^2A
secA-tanA=1/e^x.  ------------(ii)
Add.  (i)&(ii)
2secA=e^x+1/e^x
And then calculate cosA

Comment: If you choose to respond to an older Question, esp. one with upvoted and/or Accepted Answers, it scarcely helps to make your post as terse and cryptic as you did here.  See the [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and review [How do I write a good Answer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)